# What is the difference between ASP.NET site and SharePoint site?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I am new to SharePoint development. I wanted to know what is the difference between a SharePoint site and .NET site. When to use SharePoint and when .NET?

Answer (score 7):

[SharePoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint) is a massive "application platform" -- Intranet Portal, External Website, Collaboration Tool, Business Intelligence Agent, Content Management System, Document Retention System, etc -- that utilizes [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET). (SP comes standard with hundreds, if not thousands, of ASPX pages.)

On the other hand, a plain ".NET" site does not need to have SP installed: just IIS with any required ASP.NET extensions.

You use SP when you *need* it and/or are *told* to use it. It's Okay -- but generally not teriffic -- at what it does (and it does *a lot*). But it's *big* and *expensive*. (Microsoft "recommends" something like a minimum of 7 servers for a "basic" SP Farm, but it can run as a single instance.)

That's it. Really.

---

As others have pointed out, [SharePoint Foundation is "Free"](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/pages/licensing-details.aspx) insomuch as there is no *SharePoint* CAL or *SharePoint* server fees. Do not, however, discount the cost of any additional requirements..

Comment: hiii...thanks for the reply......i wanted to know when to go for sharepoint or when to .net.........supposingly I m developing an external website(say e-commerce or matrimonial)..........then whether I go for sharepoint or .net.

Comment: additionally what are the other major features in sharepoint.

 

and what is these  MOSS,WSS, workflow, infopath.

 

and there differences.

thanks

Comment: I disagree on the expensive bit, theres a free version which actually does most of what people think sharepoint does, you really only pay for the edge features and when you do its lots cheaper than the alternatives. Having said that it is big and sometimes really hard to use. If it doesnt do it OOB you really have to think twice as it can be a massive pain to customise.

Comment: @YeshAgrawal All of that is quite already sufficiently covered on MSDN and countless blogs found via google. (I do pray you never have the "experience" of being required to use InfoPath server forms.)

Answer (score 4):

SharePoint is a web based collaboration tool built using *ASP.NET*. The .NET framework (and ASP.NET) is a toolset that allows you to build applications / websites + more.

You can build on top of SharePoint / Dynamics CRM 2011 using the underlying application as a framework providing goodies such ad Security, Logging, Workflow, Persistence, File Storage, Alerting, etc.

Comment: Workflows ... gah. The nightmares! +1 for touching on the fact that SP provides *a whole host of features* that can be utilized when building applications. (Personally, I wish many of them simply didn't exist so people would *just stop trying to do it that way* ;-)

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint is an enterprise information portal, from Microsoft, that can be configured to run Intranet, Extranet and Internet sites. Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 allows people, teams and expertise to connect and collaborate. A SharePoint enterprise portal is composed of both SharePoint Portal and Windows SharePoint Services, with SharePoint being built upon WSS. WSS is typically used by small teams, projects and companies. SharePoint Server is designed for individuals, teams and projects within a medium to large company wide enterprise portal.

With ASP.net you have a very well documented, battle-hardened, mature and stable platform with a good API. ASP.net is more reliable, Simpler to customise look and feel. Pages render faster in native ASP.NET rather than being hosted in SharePoint. Server requirements are reduced as SharePoint services are not running/not required. Simpler development and deployment model and debugging (no .webpart & GAC deployment required).